# Star Wars: Flying a spaceship, or, when is a movie scene NOT canon?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship, canon, millennium-falcon

EDIT: Subsequent to a fascinating discussion with @Wad Cheber and @Mazura, I would have actually deleted the question, not because it's a dupe but because it moves into "unsolveable" issues regarding canonicity.

As we all know, it's canon that the Star Wars movies constitute the highest level of canon in the saga.

Using **only** the canonical movies, I wonder how to align one example, the issue of

**Spaceship controls**

with their contradictory portrayal.

Taking only entering and leaving hyperspace, there must be a several methods the Millennium Falcon uses.

Harrison Ford (a RL pilot, after all) himself one stated, when asked

> “I said, ‘Just make shit up!’” Ford remembered in an interview with
>   Entertainment Weekly’s Anthony Breznican. “I mean, it’s a movie, man.
>   It’s space. You don’t fly in space the way you do in an atmosphere.”

I can recall at least 4 shown ways of how the Falcon gets into and out of hyperspace:

- A handful of closely spaced levels at the top of the instrument panel. Same levers also seems to control speed in atmospheric flight.
- Get up out of your seat and throw a bunch of switches in a panel
  above the pilot to leave hyperspace.
- Do nothing obvious and just wait for the computer to finish
  calculations
- Have your droid undo some Imperial sabotage and get thrown into
  hyperspace without so much as a safety pop-up asking "are you really
  sure?"

If the movies are "infallible" and immovable canon, yet see a portrayal such as this, is there a canon explanation?

One would be the official declaration that "we're retelling the history of The Star Wars, but we take artistic liberties and our goal isn't to provide flight lessons for YT class feighters"?

Another would be quasi-technical canon explanation "controls have variable functions depending on flight situation and surrounds. Also there's more than one way to skin a cat."

Comment: Because I voted to close this as a dupe, I won't post an answer, but if I did, the answer would say "Every second of the 7 existing movies is canon".  So sayeth Disney, so sayeth Lucas, so sayeth we all.

Comment: I understand your point about the use of controls being inconsistent, but I don't get your point about artificial gravity. If artificial gravity were possible, why couldn't it adjust to compensate for the [fictitious force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force) normally felt due to acceleration (the G-force) by generating an equal and opposite force?

Comment: "Lucas always made it clear that he was not beholden to the EU. **He set the films he created as the canon. This includes the six Star Wars episodes, and the many hours of content he developed and produced in Star Wars: The Clone Wars. These stories are the immovable objects of Star Wars history, the characters and events to which all other tales must align**" [Source](http://www.starwars.com/news/the-legendary-star-wars-expanded-universe-turns-a-new-page)

Comment: I'm inclined to say that this shouldn't be closed, but maybe reworked a bit.

Comment: @WadCheber Note: I specifically ONLY speak of the movies. No derivative works!

Comment: Just because the canon is wrong and or inconsistent and or completely nuts, does not make it any less canon.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Yeah, my question was getting way too unwieldy (as if it isn't already borderline), so I'll leave it for now. It has to do with on one hand, crew having something like artificial gravity, yet BB-8 rolling around like a pinball, including nearly bouncing against the ceiling.

Comment: @Marakai - Doesn't matter.  The question you asked here is answered in that post, so this is a dupe.

Comment: @WadCheber I'm familiar with both the answer and the topic in general. It does not answer my question! Maybe I'm not expressing it right?

Comment: @Marakai - Possible, but unlikely.  The answer to the question I linked describes exactly how canonicity is determined, and it clearly says that every part of every SW movie is canon.  That means that any question about what is or isn't canon in SW is probably a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Sorry @WadCheber but then you haven't actually read my question. I'm not interested in some form of quasi-religious dogma. It sounds like belief in literal infallibility of the bible. But let's take it like that: Star Wars exegesis: how are we to interpret the Truth of the movies, if they contradict "Reality" (the reality of the galaxy long time ago and far far away)

Comment: I have read it.  Is the canon sometimes contradictory?  Yep.  Does that affect it's canonicity?  Nope.

Comment: My advice:  Trim this question down, and make it easier to understand and less of a rant.  It's very unwieldy at the moment, and the signal to noise ratio is decidedly skewed towards "noise".

Comment: Will delete this question, methinks. I'm clearly not getting through and am starting to feel distinctly uncomfortable with some of the infallibility belief. I don't want to end up burnt at the stake for heresy. Eppur se muove!

Comment: You're confusing facts with our opinions.  We're not saying we like this, or agree with it - we're saying "that's the way it is".  Contradictions don't change the fact that Lucasfilm and Disney sets the canon, and they have made it clear that everything from the movies is canon, whether or not it contradicts itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39709/discussion-between-wad-cheber-and-marakai).

Comment: I think you mean *retconned*, not *canon*.

Comment: @WadCheber - [THERE.ARE.EIGHT.MOVIES!!](https://media.giphy.com/media/3oEjHENcaDRxifXDwc/giphy.gif)

Comment: When playing computer games, I have these little tricks called "remapping keys" and "setting profiles".  It allows the same button to do different things depending on what program or scenario I am in.  While I am aware that Star Wars was *a long time ago (in a galaxy far, far away)*, I suspect they probably cracked the same technology at some point prior to FTL travel...

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR Just because the canon conflicts with itself does not make it any less canon**

The movies are canon, and that is the end of the discussion.  There are many places where it is severely inconsistent and or wrong, but it is still canon none the less.

Eg We know that The Force is:

> The force is an energy field created by all living things, it
>   surrounds us, it penetrates us, it binds the galaxy together

But on the other hand we are somehow supposed to also believe that the Force is:

> Midi-chlorians

What?  You can see that sometimes the canon is clearly wrong.  But it is still canon anyway.

Comment: Don't forget "Han didn't shoot first"!

Comment: The first is the layman explanation of what the Force is. The second is the academic treatment. You tell a layman "colours depend on the shades and tints of light objects reflect into your eyes" while you would tell a physics student "colours depend on the frequencies of light that are not absorbed by the electron fields in an object's constituent atoms" (off-the-cuff example)

Comment: Your example is incorrect. [Midi-chlorians *communicate* with the Force, they aren't literally the Force themselves.](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/114062/31936)